# I have not found the appropriate character that resembles a vertical bar

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I'm trying to do these integration steps, but I have not found the appropriate character that resembles a vertical bar.

[image: Imagem]

The bars in question are the ones I highlighted below:

[image]

This is the output that Mathematica software provides:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics, setspace}

\newcommand{\mathsym}[1]{{}}
\newcommand{\unicode}[1]{{}}

\newcounter{mathematicapage}
\begin{document}

V=\int_0^H 1 \, dV\Rightarrow \left(V=\int_0^H A' \, dh\right)\Rightarrow \left(V=\int_0^H \frac{A h^2}{H^2} \, dh\right)\Rightarrow \left(V=\frac{A \int_0^H h^2 \, dh}{H^2}\right)\Rightarrow \left(V=\frac{A}{H^2}\left|\frac{h^3}{3}\right|\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 H \\
 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)\right)\Rightarrow V=\frac{A H^3}{3 H^2}\Rightarrow V=\frac{A H}{3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your equation has a red box, but you talk about a vertical bar. What do you need?

Comment: Is `V=\left|\frac{A H^3}{3 H^2}\right|^{H}_{0}` acceptable? Please correct your MWE (delete all what is not needed, add missing math environment).

Comment: `'V=\frac{A}{H^2}\left|\frac{h^3}{3}\right|_0^H`. If you need it bigger, try `\bigg` or `\Bigg`.

Comment: On closer inspection, you already have `\left|` `\right|` in your code. What is missing for you? The array attempt is unnecessary, you can use `^` and `_`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to get the lines is `\left|` and `\right|`. But might I suggest replacing (4) with (7) in this derivation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
V &= \int_0^H dV\\
  &= \int_0^H A'\,dh\\
  &= \int_0^H \frac{Ah^2}{H^2}\,dh\\
  &= \frac{A}{H^2}\left|\frac{h^3}{3}\right|_0^H\\
  &= \frac{A}{H^2}\cdot\frac{H^3}{3}\\
  &= \frac{1}{3}AH.
\end{align}

\begin{equation}
V=\frac{A}{H^2}\left[\frac{h^3}{3}\right]_0^H
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Frequently, you'll want just a single, right bar. In which case `\left.` and `\right|` can be used.

Comment: I appreciate the care in showing all the steps I needed. I've never worked with Latex. I use the Mathematica program to export the code, but I never compiled it to see the result.

Comment: What is the reason why you suggest replacing (4) with (7) in this derivation?

Comment: Because | | is an absolute value where as [ ] are just brackets.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I agree with your decision to delete my answer, because at least for me the answer is visible.

Answer (score 2):

Let me extend my comment to an answer...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\delimitershortfall-1sp
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}

\begin{document}
\[
V=\abs*{\frac{A H^3}{3 H^2}}_0^H
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @LCarvalho, sorry, I don't understand you. I just down-wrote your highlighted part of your equation where no `h`, but replace `H` with `h` should not be big deal ... Please, consider my first comment and correct your question as I suggested (delete all not relevant stuff and define math environment). Help us to help you.

Comment: You forgive me. I did not understand you gave a generic example. I'll delete the comment. My intention was not to be rude. I'm Brazilian and I may have expressed myself wrong.

Comment: @LCarvalho, I only worry, that I miss something in your question.  You are not rude at all :). If you like that I edit your equation like *TH* do, I can extend my answer. Many greetings to Brazil (huge and very beautiful country ...)

Comment: I am always grateful to everyone who helps me on these sites in general. We Brazilians are going through a political crisis and I am struggling to learn new things that make me better every day.